# Custom ZoomIn / ZoomOut with Mapbox / Leaflet JS

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to zoom out 2 zoom levels when clicking on the "-" button of the zoom control. I believe that I should use ZoomOut(2), but I am not sure how to assign this method to the - button.
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-map-class/

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't: instead of changing the behavior of the zoom control, you can [copy it](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Zoom.js), rename it, and change the behavior of your new control, like L.control.doubleZoom